# Auto restrict runtime access to a property

Tags: c#, properties

Is it possible to have a class with unknown amount or types of properties, that will restrict the property access if needed, in runtime.

For example, if we have the following class:

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, accessing the class property outcome will depend on some runtime state, that is controllable by classes that are aggregated to it in some way.

A possible solution, would be to add some public boolean variable that can be set, then determain the behaviour by it.

For example:

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public bool CanAccess { get; set; }

        private string _someProperty;

        public string SomeProperty
        {
            get
            {
                if (CanAccess)
                {
                    return _someProperty;
                }

                throw new Exception();
            }
            set
            {
                if (CanAccess)
                {
                    _someProperty = value;
                }

                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
```

This solution however, will require the class implementor to:

1. Do it right
2. Do it for all properties

I am not sure it is possible, but I want to implement that class in some way that will eliminate the need to check this "CanAccess" feild for every property.

This further means that if in the future I add some more properties to that class, they will also comply that "CanAccess" state automatically.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Look into AOP - Aspect Oriented Programming. aka "rewriting your compiled code". There is absolutely no built-in support for what you're asking. Some 3rd party systems that deal with AOP, such as "PostSharp", can probably help you.

Comment: Thank you, i'll look into it. 
Do you know any non-commercial libraries that does similar things?